# Counting chars without comments

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop, comments

I'm trying to make a function that can count all chars in a string input, but without counting any comments (// or /*)

So far it works perfectly with lines after //. I splitted my String by every new line and I only count the lines chars if it doesn't include //

This is the code so far:

```
function findComments() {

    var string = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var splittedString = string.split("\n");

    var count = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < splittedString.length; i++) {
        while (countStars) {
            if(splittedString[i].indexOf("*/") > -1) {
                countStars = false;
            }
            continue;
        }

        if(splittedString[i].indexOf("/*") > -1) {
            var countStars = true;
        }

        if(splittedString[i].indexOf("//") === -1) {

            var chars = splittedString[i].split("");
            for (var j = 0; j < chars.length; j++) {
                count++;
            }
        }

    }
    console.log(count);
}
```

As I mentioned, it should just continue the loop until it finds an ending of the comment ( */ ). So far this doesn't work

Any help is very much appreciated! :)

Comment: You can ignore all after // but you will need to handle multi lines for /* */ - can you create a [mcve] using the `<>` snippet editor?

Comment: Yes and it's hard to handle multiple lines, cos i need to somehow continue the loop until i find a */

Comment: Just remove them before you split into lines. https://blog.ostermiller.org/find-comment

Comment: i would like to do it without regex, is there a way to remove it without?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var inComment = false, count = 0;
 for(const line of splittedStrings){
  var end = -1;
  if(inComment){
   end = line.indexOf("*/");
   if(end === -1){
     count += line.length;
     continue;
   } else {
     count += end;
     inComment = false;
   }
  }
  const single = line.indexOf("//", end);
  const multi = line.indexOf("/*", end);
  if(single + multi === -2) continue;
  if(multi !== -1 && multi < single){
    //got a multiline comment
    inComment = true;
    count += line.length - (multi + 2);
 } else{
   //got a single line comment
   count += line.length - (single + 2);
 }
}
```

Just keep a flag if youre inside a multiline comment

Comment: nice solution! one problem tho, it doesn't seem to count when i make a new line inside of the /* .. */

Comment: Furthermore, can you elaborate what the for loop (const line of splittedStrings) does?

Comment: @gustav actually it should work. The for loop is just the beautiful form of your `for(var i = 0...` loop

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to declare the countStars outside the for loop, because you are checking for that variable even before declaration
you should get the continue statement out of the while loop. Continue will hit the while statement again.

```
for(var i = 0; i<10; ++i)
{
    var j = 10;
    var k = true;
    while(j > 0 && k)
    {
       j--;
       if(j == 8)
       {k == false;}
    }
    if(!k)
       continue;
}
```

Comment: I can't put the continue out of the while loop, it has to be activated from within

Comment: add a Boolean variable inside the while. Set it to true . And then use that variable to call the continue statement .

Comment: Do u have an example? :' D

Comment: Added an example to the answer .

Comment: I'm not sure i understand, where do u use the countStars in this example?

Comment: This is only an example , Instead of continue , you can use a variable like k which you can set it to false to break out of the loop .

Comment: Yes but if this is done, it would iterate through next line and not go into the while loop because it is now false, i have to stay in the while loop while continuing somehow

Answer (score 0):

This could be further improved, but you could split your original text by '/*' and subtract the length of block comments from your count. This means counting block comments unnecessarily, but it gets the job done.

Splitting text like this, you know that each second item in array is your block comment.

```
var blockComments = string.split('/*');

function blockCommentsLength(array){
   length = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i = i +2){
      length += array[i].length
   }

   return length;
}

...

console.log(count - blockCommentsLength(blockComments));
```

Comment: That is actually not a bad idea! Thanks alot :)

Comment: How would i be able to identify the */ ending of the comments and start counting again?